# onblur even is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, onchange, onblur

I have a form having 5 fields and a submit button.
On one of the fields i am having an onblur event but if the user changes the value in that textbox and directly clicks on submit button then in that case onblur is notgetting triggered or not working.
Even onchange is not working in that case.

What if i use onkeyup and down but if user used mouse for pasting the data?

Please help!

Thanks and regards
Asus.

Comment: show your html code...

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the `onchange`event or `oninput` event to track when the input data is being modified. Then you can use the `onsubmit` event to call whatever function you would like.